# How can I create a draft on a current thread for a Gmail add-on?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api, google-workspace-add-ons

I'm trying to make an add-on for Gmail in Apps Script that generates reply drafts by analyzing the thread content.

When I'm using a contextual trigger, the event passed to the function contains the messageId and I can get the message and call the function `GmailApp.GmailMessage.createDraftReplyAll` to create the draft.
However in order to see the reply draft, I have to go back to the inbox and access the thread again. The behavior I want is to see the reply draft on the thread I'm currently on.

An other way I've tried is to use a compose trigger instead but there is no information in the event that can help me obtain the last message (or the entire thread) content.
Here is the event I get:

```
{"clientPlatform":"web","draftMetadata":{"subject":"Re: test","ccRecipients":[],"bccRecipients":[],"toRecipients":["mymail@gmail.com"]},"hostApp":"gmail","gmail":{"toRecipients":["mymail@gmail.com"],"subject":"Re: test"},"commonEventObject":{"hostApp":"GMAIL","platform":"WEB"}}
```